# Split a csv file into smaller files when integer found in first column

Tags: bash, python, text-processing

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
1,'someval','otherval',,,,,
'','someotherval','some_otherval',,,,,
1BSD,'',,,,,
2,'val',,,,,
,,,,,,
2BSD,,,,,,
2BCD,,,,,,
```

Now, I want to split file whenever the first column of the new row is an integer value.

So, then for the above csv input< I must get 2 new files with contents:

```
1,'someval','otherval',,,,,
,'someotherval','some_otherval',,,,,
1BSD,'val',,,,,
```

and

```
2,'val',,,,,
,,,,,,
2BSD,,,,,,
2BCD,,,,,,
```

respectively.

How can I accomplish this using Bash and/or Python ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `csplit` utility to split on a regular expression e.g.

```
csplit -z file.csv '/^[0-9]\+,/' '{*}'
80
42
```

(the counts indicate the number of characters output into each file - you can suppress them by adding the `-s` option).

The output files are named `xx00`, `xx01` etc. by default - there are options to change the prefix and suffix if you wish.

Ex.

```
$ csplit -z file.csv '/^[0-9]\+,/' '{*}'
80
42
$ head xx*
==> xx00 <==
1,'someval','otherval',,,,,
'','someotherval','some_otherval',,,,,
1BSD,'',,,,,

==> xx01 <==
2,'val',,,,,
,,,,,,
2BSD,,,,,,
2BCD,,,,,,
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. In my view csplit can only split 1 file to 2, it cannot split a file into multiple files.

Comment: @kashish did you try it? it *should* split into as many files as there are matches - I can't verify that because your sample only contains 2

Comment: I tried. It says `csplit: *}: bad repetition count`

Comment: @kashish sorry - I can't reproduce that error. Maybe you could update your question with a more representative sample of your input data?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to see how much of this I could do with `sed`, and I did manage to do quite a lot of it. We can write files with `sed` using the `w` and `W` commands, but I couldn't think of a way to write a different file with each iteration of a `sed` loop, so I had to use a shell loop. `sed` is probably the wrong tool to use for this job, and there's probably a nicer way to do it with `sed`. Anyway, here's what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed ':a;N;s/\n/\x00/; ta' input | sed -r 's/\x00([0-9]+(,|\x00|$))/\n\1/g' > edited
n=0
while [ -s edited ]; do 
    ((n++))
    sed -n '1p' edited > csv-"$n"
    sed -i '1d' edited
done
sed -i 'y/\x00/\n/' csv-*
rm edited
```

#### Comments

- replace newlines with the null character `\x00` using a `sed` loop. This is so that we can use newlines as meaningful separators later.

  ```
  sed ':a;N;s/\n/\x00/; ta' input
  ```
- pipe the result and add newlines before integers that were in the first field, and write the result to a file, `edited`

  ```
  | sed -r 's/\x00([0-9]+(,|\x00|$))/\n\1/g' > edited
  ```
- initialise a variable to increment

  ```
  n=0
  ```
- as long as `edited` is not empty, do things

  ```
  while [ -s edited ]; do
  ```
- increment `n`

  ```
  ((n++))
  ```
- write the first line of `edited` to a new file `csv-$n` where `$n` is the current value of `n`

  ```
  sed -n '1p' edited > csv-"$n"
  ```
- delete the first line of `edited`

  ```
  sed -i '1d' edited
  ```

  that's the end of the loop, and because we only have one line for each file we want to write, this isn't as slow as processing every line of the original file in a loop, but still, it's slow!
- for each file we created, turn the null characters back into newlines

  ```
  sed -i 'y/\x00/\n/' csv-*
  ```
- delete the intermediate file

  ```
  rm edited
  ```